# Fix Widows 10 boot issue without an installation media

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have two disks with Windows 10 installed on each. One of the disks will not boot to Windows because "the boot file contains no valid information for an operating system". I know how to fix this with an installation media, but my question is how to do it without? I have access to the system files of the system that doesn't want to boot.

Comment: You will need to boot some sort of external disc, so why not down-load a copy of the installation disc?

Comment: @AFH Because I don't have 8 gb of free disk space.

Comment: How are you accessing the system files on the unbootable system? Whatever OS you are using for that may have some system repair utilities on it. A W10 installation disc image is ~4GB, not 8GB, but with less than 4GB of disc space you will rapidly run into problems with W10.

Comment: @AFH The unbootable system sits on a 500gb SSD and I can access it from my current disk which is about 10% of that and runs Windows 10. Since the issue is known, I was wondering whether replacing the invalid files could be a solution. I can run applications on my smaller SSD.

Comment: If you can mount it, then you can use it for whatever work space you need to down-load and create the installation disc.

Comment: @AFH I have used the Windows Download Tool to do that, but it requires me to have 8 gb on the small disk. I don't have any option to change the disk it is using.

Comment: Then you'll have to move some files temporarily on to the other disc: media files are usually the largest. Make sure all your back-ups are up-to-date before you start any sort of recovery.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for your advice. I have resolved the issue using an installation media. Seems like the only way to do it right now ;/

Comment: Glad you've fixed it.